# Compute volume over a solid cone $\int_K (x^2+y^2)dV$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a few exercises on computing the volume of a solid cone, however the inequalities introduced in the exercises aren't something I have faced with before. So I would really just appreciate some hints on how to tackle exercises where inequalities for $z$ are given as so $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le z\le1$.

For example, compute the integral $\int_K (x^2+y^2)dV$ where $K$ is the solid cone.

I can see the integral bounds for $z$ as $\int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^1dz$

Althlugh for $y$ I have assumed this $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \le 1 \implies y \le \sqrt{1-x^2}$

Such that $\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dy$ as for the integral bounds of $x$ $\int_{-1}^1$

Which gives me $$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^1(x^2+y^2)dzdydx$$

Comment: Are you familiar with cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: as @Zanzag has mentioned, I believe you can swap your rectangular to cylindrical coordinates and integrate.

Comment: Even spherical coordinates would be better, but cylindrical is the standard.

Comment: @TedShifrin I wasn't so sure on how to proceed with the inequality I was given. I have tried this for cylindrical coordinates $\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^1dz \int _0^1 r^3 dr$?

Comment: Of course your lower $z$-limit should be $r$. That's one of the whole reasons for the change to cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah yes! I missed that - thank you for the insight :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are evaluating volume integral over a region which is cone, cylindrical or spherical coordinates is easier.

The cone you are referring to is a standard inverted cone with vertex at the origin and a flat top surface at $z = 1$

In cylindrical coordinates, $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq z \leq 1$ translates to $r \leq z \leq 1$ and $0 \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq 1 \implies 0 \leq r \leq 1, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

In spherical coordinates, $x = \rho \cos\theta \sin\phi, y = \rho \sin\theta \sin\phi, z = \rho \cos\phi$

We measure radial distance from the origin so lower bound of $\rho$ is $0$ and if we take a ray from the origin, it is bound above by the top surface $z = 1 = \rho \cos\phi \implies \rho = \sec\phi$

To find the limits of $\phi$, note that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq z \implies \rho \sin \phi \leq \rho \cos\phi, \text {so } \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$

Finally the limits of $\theta$ is $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

Comment: For this step $\rho \sin \phi \le \rho \cos \phi  \implies \phi \le \frac{\pi}{4}$ what reasoning do I follow to get the final inequality? do I divide $\sin \phi$ on both sides and plug in the value 1 into $\phi$?

Comment: Yes it becomes $\tan\phi \leq 1$